# A way to round Floats down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, floating-point, rounding

Float round rounds it up or down. I always need it to round down.

I have the solution but i dont really like it... Maybe there is a better way.

This is what i want:

```
1.9999.round_down(2) 
#=> 1.99
1.9901.round_down(2)
#=> 1
```

I came up with this solution but i would like to know if there is a better solution(I dont like that i convert the float twice). Is there already a method for this? Because I found it pretty strange that I couldnt find it.

```
class Float
  def round_down(n=0)
    ((self * 10**n).to_i).to_f/10**n 
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with negative numbers? Toward negative infinity or towards zero?

Comment: It's not exactly what you want (since you will always lose the decimal part), but if you convert to an integer you will always round down - `1.9901.to_i` - can be much better depending on your scenario.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on answer from @kimmmo this should be a little more efficient:

```
class Float
  def round_down n=0
  s = self.to_s
  l = s.index('.') + 1 + n
  s.length <= l ? self : s[0,l].to_f
  end
end

1.9991.round_down(3)
 => 1.999
1.9991.round_down(2)
 => 1.99
1.9991.round_down(0)
 => 1.0
1.9991.round_down(5)
 => 1.9991
```

or based on answer from @steenslag, probably yet more efficient as there is no string conversion:

```
class Float
  def round_down n=0
    n < 1 ? self.to_i.to_f : (self - 0.5 / 10**n).round(n)
  end
end
```

Comment: This answer is also good. Still prefer @kimmmo his solution because it is shorter and easier to read. But this is also a good answer! Thanks

Comment: @michaelkoper: look into the second solution - I think it is more straightforward and yet more efficient.

Comment: In my quick speed test, this string version is about twice as fast as kimmmo's `split` version, and the second version using actual math is about 4 times faster still. Math: good for numbers.

Comment: I have problems with second one (n=5): with 0 the result is -0.00001, with 0.0000001 the result is -0.0

Comment: since someone commented on my answer after 5 years and i'm here, i would just like to say that using `s.index(?., 1)`  is probably even faster. the math version is a winner in any case :)

Comment: 0.0.round_down(2) will return -0.01

Comment: how can I overwrite Float class in ruby?

Answer (score 47):

```
1.9999.to_i
#=> 1
1.9999.floor
#=> 1
```

*answered 1 sec ago fl00r*

```
"%.2f" % 1.93213
#=> 1.93
```

@kimmmo is right.

```
class Float
  def round_down(n=0)
    self.to_s[/\d+\.\d{#{n}}/].to_f
  end
end
```

Comment: `"%.2f" % 1.935 => 1.94`, the asker wants it to return 1.93

Answer (score 10):

Looks like you just want to strip decimals after *n*

```
class Float
  def round_down(n=0)
    int,dec=self.to_s.split('.')
    "#{int}.#{dec[0...n]}".to_f
  end
end


1.9991.round_down(3)
 => 1.999
1.9991.round_down(2)
 => 1.99
1.9991.round_down(0)
 => 1.0
1.9991.round_down(10)
 => 1.9991
```

(Edit: slightly more efficient version without the regexp)

Comment: Shouldn't `1.9991.round_down(0)` return `1` instead of `1.0`?

Comment: @mischa `1.0` just means it's still a float. I suppose you could build in functionality to use `to_i` if `n == 0`, but that could probably give someone headaches debugging.

Comment: You are doing math with strings.. how disgusting! :)

Comment: This is much slower than geronime's versions!

Comment: Not sure if this is a change in Ruby since 2011, or purely the code, but with the edited version `"#{int}.#{dec[0..n]}".to_f`, `1.9991.round_down(2)` returns `1.999` instead of `1.99`.

Comment: hmm. `"abc"[0..2]` would be "abc" for any ruby. i suppose `#{dec[0...n]}` would work.

Comment: it return 0.0 if i have 0.5 converted to round_down(2)

Answer (score 5):

You could use the floor method

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Float.html#M000142

Comment: Float#floor will never turn 1.999 into 1.99.

Comment: I think floor is the same as to_i. It returns the highest Integer.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You could've added an example though.

Answer (score 5):

For anybody viewing this question in modern times (Ruby 2.4+), `floor` now accepts an argument.

```
> 1.9999.floor(1)
 => 1.9
> 1.9999.floor(2)
 => 1.99
> 1.9999.floor(3)
 => 1.999
> 1.9999.ceil(2)
 => 2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby 1.9:

```
class Float
  def floor_with_prec(prec = 0)
    (self - 0.5).round(prec)
  end
end
```

Comment: `(1.9990 - 0.5).round(2)` => 1.5 (asker wants it to return 1.99)

Comment: @kimmmo Right. You can get around that with a minor revision, I think: `(self - 0.5 / 10**prec).round(prec)`. I'm not sure whether this will get beaten up by floating point issues, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Float
  def rownd_down(digits = 1)
    ("%.#{digits+1}f" % self)[0..-2].to_f
  end 
end

> 1.9991.rownd_down(3)
=> 1.999
> 1.9991.rownd_down(2)
=> 1.99
> 1.9991.rownd_down(10)
> 1.9991
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a bug for the answers that try to calculate float in round_down method.

```
> 8.7.round_down(1)
=> 8.7
> 8.7.round_down(2)
=> 8.69
```

you can use bigdecimal, integer or maybe string to do all the math but float.

```
 > 8.7 - 0.005
 => 8.694999999999999
```

Here is my solution:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

class Float
  def floor2(n = 0)
    BigDecimal.new(self.to_s).floor(n).to_f
  end
end

> 8.7.floor2(1)
=> 8.7
> 8.7.floor2(2)
=> 8.7

> 1.9991.floor(3)
=> 1.999
> 1.9991.floor(2)
=> 1.99
> 1.9991.floor(1)
=> 1.9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Float
  def round_down(n)
    num = self.round(n)
    num > self ? (num - 0.1**n) : num
  end
end
```

`56.0.round_down(-1) =  50`. Works with negative numbers as well, if you agree that rounding down makes a number smaller: `-56.09.round_down(1) = -56.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Found this article helpful: https://richonrails.com/articles/rounding-numbers-in-ruby

Here are the round up and down methods:

```
class Float
  def round_down(exp = 0)
   multiplier = 10 ** exp
   ((self * multiplier).floor).to_f/multiplier.to_f
  end

  def round_up(exp = 0)
   multiplier = 10 ** exp
   ((self * multiplier).ceil).to_f/multiplier.to_f
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

```
> (1.999).to_i.to_f
```

For rounding up you could just use

```
> (1.999+1).to_i.to_f
```