# Rails round number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rounding

I have number `num = 24.89808` and want to round it to `24.89`

How can i do it?

i tried `num.round(2)` but it gives me `24.9` also `number_to_currency=>24.90`

Comment: This question is duplicated. Please check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7091178/2245697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about *rounding*, `24.9` is by all means the correct result. Whether you are interested in *ceiling it*, here you go:

```
(24.89808 * 100).floor / 100.0
#⇒ "24.89"
```

Answer (score 2):

First convert that into a decimal and then round it two two places,

Try this command,

```
num.to_d.round(2, :truncate).to_f

2.2.4 :040 > num = 24.89808
 => 24.89808 
2.2.4 :041 > num.to_d.round(2,:truncate).to_f
 => 24.89
```

Comment: `bigdecimal` is not appearing everywhere out of the box. Alsoo, since you are already using it,, it has explicit `#truncate` method.

Comment: But, its working fine and will solve the requirement.

Comment: It is working fine _if and only_ `bigdecimal` was previously required. Yes, Rails does this for you, as it does many other unneeded things.

Comment: So, We can utilize the methods rails giving us, anyways anything is fine. :)